# How to access functions of a binary from integration tests in Rust's Cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In my cargo project I have defined two binary targets. How can I access functions defined in the binary from an integration test?

```
[package]
name = "passman"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[[bin]]
name = "passmand"
path = "src/daemon/main.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "passman"
path = "src/cli/main.rs"
```

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── cli
│   │   ├── argument
│   │   │   └── mod.rs
│   │   └── main.rs
│   └── daemon
│       ├── entry_value.rs
│       ├── main.rs
│       ├── passman_crypto.rs
│       ├── passman.service
│       └── password_file.rs   <- i want to access functions defined in this
└── tests
    ├── password_file_tests.rs   <- this is my integration test
    └── test.py
```

I tried to access the file with `extern crate passmand;`, but Cargo just complains:

```
 --> tests/password_file_tests.rs:6:1
  |
6 | extern crate passmand;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

Comment: `passmand` is not a crate, it's a binary in your crate. Moreover you can't use binary-only crates as a library anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @mcarton. I understand what you're saying, but that doesn't get me anywhere. Do you see a solution?

Comment: You have to add a `[lib]` section to your crate and define the common functions there.

Comment: @mcarton You're saying "crate" when you're referring to the "package". `passmand` *is* a crate, but it's a binary crate, so it cannot be imported with `extern crate`.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the following codes work around.

```
#[path = "../src/bin/some_bin.rs"]
mod some_bin;

use some_bin::XXX;

#[test]
fn func_test() {
// ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Integration tests are for testing libraries, not binaries. You *could* expose functions that you want to test by giving the crate a library target too. However, if you don't want people to use it as a library, you may as well just write unit tests within your project `src` directory instead. It is most common and idiomatic in Rust to write unit tests in the same files as the code they are testing.

If you actually want to test the binary - e.g. to make sure that the CLI interface works as expected - then you can run it as a binary. There's probably a more reliable way to get the path to the binary (edits welcome!) but this should work:

```
use std::process::Command;
use std::path::PathBuf;

#[test]
fn test_cli() {
    let mut path = PathBuf::from(std::env::var("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR").unwrap());
    path.push("target/debug/passman");
    let output = Command::new(path)
        .arg("--an-arg")
        .output()
        .expect("Failed to execute command");

    assert_eq!(&output.stdout[..], b"Hello, world!\n");
}
```

Comment: There is also the `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` variable that would make the code clearer probably

Comment: The path to the binary being compiled during testing [can be found](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-sets-for-crates) with `env!("CARGO_BIN_EXE_<name>")`