# How can I use integration tests with some of my utility functions?

Tags: testing, rust, integration-testing

How I organized my code:

```
- src
  - main.rs
  - utils.rs
- tests
  - integration-tests.rs
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve would be to test my utils with some integration tests, withe the possibility of expanding the utils to become a larger module in the next future.

My problem is that I cannot access the utils module from the integration tests:

```
use utils;

#[test]
fn get_one_test() {
    assert_eq!(1, utils::get_one());
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Isn't the utils its own module? Why can't I import it with `use`?

Comment: Integration tests only see the crate as an outside observer and thus only has access to your crate's public API. Use a [unit test](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/testing/unit_testing.html) if you want to verify private functions.

Comment: So it is not possible to do integration test a program? What should I do with a program if the code in main and its utilities grow too big to be covered by unit testing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access functions of a binary from integration tests in Rust's Cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63180875/how-to-access-functions-of-a-binary-from-integration-tests-in-rusts-cargo)

Comment: @Jmb Not really. I don't want to test all the code in main as a CLI command. Just a big chuck of the code I'm using there which resides in a separate file.

Comment: But what you are trying to do is not integration tests. You're using the wrong tool.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Is the meaning of integration tests different in the rust world? If I wanted to test a function or a class I would say it's a unit test. In my case I've create a more complex set of functionalities with different components interacting with each other, also making request to the file system and to the network. I'd normally call a test for the resulting "module" an integration test.

Comment: @heapOverflow note that according to the [Wikipedia page on unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing), a unit is a _"set of one or more computer program modules."_ The same page then states that _"a unit could be an entire module"_ although it is usually smaller (e.g. a single function or class). In Rust integration tests apply to a single crate taken as a whole, anything smaller is handled by unit tests.